# aggregate results returning null when running test

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Lines from 71 to 75 are not covered in Apex class. The specific lines are:

```
for(aggregateresult agr : [select count(id),ownerID from case where Status!='closed' AND RecordTypeID =: recid AND CreatedDate >=:t AND OwnerID IN : Activesessionusers GROUP BY OwnerID LIMIT 50000])
{
    system.debug('agr results'+agr);
    Useropen.put((id)agr.get('ownerID'),(integer)agr.get('expr0'));
}
```

Apex class

```
public class TestUserOnline 
{
    public static map<ID,id> m1()
    {
        set<ID> userslist = new set<ID>();
        set<ID> Activesessionusers = new set<ID>();
        set<ID> Noactiveusers  = new set<id>();
        list<Assignment_Groups__c> alist = new list<Assignment_Groups__c>(); 
        list<Assignment_Groups__c> finallist = new list<Assignment_Groups__c>();
        list<Assignment_Groups__c> inactivefinal = new list <Assignment_Groups__c> ();

 // Getting the list of all active users under assignment groups        
    for(Assignment_Groups__c ac : [select User__c,Active__c,User_Active__c,Group_Name__c from Assignment_Groups__c])
       {    
          if(ac.Active__c == 'True' && ac.User_Active__c =='True')
            {
            userslist.add(ac.user__c);
            }
           else
           {
            Noactiveusers.add(ac.user__c);
           }
        }

      system.debug('list of Active users from all groups' + userslist);
      system.debug('list of No Active users from all groups' + Noactiveusers);
//Getting the list of active sessions for active users 
        if(userslist.size() >0)
        {
           datetime currenttime = system.now();
           list<AuthSession> Activesessions = [SELECT LastModifiedDate,LoginType,NumSecondsValid,CreatedDate,SessionType, UsersId FROM AuthSession WHERE SessionType = 'UI'AND LoginType = 'Application'AND ParentId = null AND UsersId IN : userslist];
           system.debug('Active sessions' + Activesessions);

            for(AuthSession am : Activesessions)
            {
              if(userslist.contains(am.UsersId) && am.LastModifiedDate >= am.CreatedDate && currenttime <= am.LastModifiedDate + am.NumSecondsValid )
                {
                    system.debug('active users details' + am);
                    system.debug('active users valid until' + am.LastModifiedDate + am.NumSecondsValid);
                    Activesessionusers.add(am.UsersId); 
                }  
            }
            system.debug('active users' + Activesessionusers);
        }  
 // Collectig the list of online users for individual groups 
 if(Activesessionusers.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Assignment_Group_Name__c ag : [select id, (select User__c,Group_Name__c,IsOnline__c from Assignment_Groups__r where Active__c ='True' AND User_Active__c ='True' AND User__c IN :Activesessionusers)from Assignment_Group_Name__c])
          {
            system.debug('active session user record details' + ag);
            for (Assignment_Groups__c agr : ag.Assignment_Groups__r)
                {
                    if(agr.Group_Name__c == ag.id)
                    {
                     agr.IsOnline__c = true;
                     finallist.add(agr); 
                     //a.add(agr.User__c);
                    }
                }

           }
         // below code is used to get the open cases of each logged in user from last 30 day's 
        Map<id,integer>Useropen = new Map<id,integer>();
         Integer days = integer.valueof(Label.DateFilter_For_Round_Robin_Assignment);
        system.debug('number of days'+ days);
         datetime s = system.now();
         datetime t = s.addDays(-days);
        system.debug('last 30 days'+ t);
         Id recid = Schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Customer Support').getRecordTypeId(); 
        system.debug('recordtype id'+ recid);
        for(aggregateresult agr : [select count(id),ownerID from case where Status!='closed' AND RecordTypeID =: recid AND CreatedDate >=:t AND OwnerID IN : Activesessionusers GROUP BY OwnerID LIMIT 50000])
          {
               system.debug('agr results'+agr);
               Useropen.put((id)agr.get('ownerID'),(integer)agr.get('expr0'));
           }
      system.debug('user open'+ Useropen);
        if(Useropen.size() >0)
        {
            for(Assignment_Groups__c agc : [select User__c,Case_Count__c from Assignment_Groups__c where User__c IN: Useropen.keyset()])
          {
                agc.Case_Count__c = Useropen.get(agc.User__c);
                alist.add(agc);
            }
        }

    }
       //updating the status for logged in users.
        if(finallist.size() > 0)
        {
            update finallist; 
            system.debug('final updated list' + finallist);
        }
       // Updating case count for logged in users.
        if(alist.size() >0)
        {
           update alist;
        }
        //Collecting the list of offline and active users under individual groups 
 if(Activesessionusers.size() > 0)
    {    
       for(Assignment_Group_Name__c ab : [select id, (select User__c,IsOnline__c,Active__c,User_Active__c,Group_Name__c from Assignment_Groups__r where Active__c ='True' AND User_Active__c ='True' AND User__c NOT IN :Activesessionusers) from Assignment_Group_Name__c])
       {
        for (Assignment_Groups__c offline : ab.Assignment_Groups__r)
            {
                if(offline.Group_Name__c == ab.Id && offline.Active__c == 'True' && offline.User_Active__c == 'True')
                {
                  offline.IsOnline__c = false;
                  inactivefinal.add(offline);  
                  system.debug('Active but no session users'+ offline);
                }
            }
        }   
    }
      //collecting the list of Non active users under individual groups
 If(Noactiveusers.size() > 0)
    {
      for(Assignment_Group_Name__c ac : [select id, (select User__c,IsOnline__c,Active__c,User_Active__c,Group_Name__r.ID from Assignment_Groups__r where User__c IN :Noactiveusers) from Assignment_Group_Name__c])
       {
        for (Assignment_Groups__c Noactive : ac.Assignment_Groups__r)
           {
               if(Noactive.Active__c == 'False' || Noactive.User_Active__c == 'False')
               {
                   system.debug(' No Active users'+ Noactive);
                   Noactive.IsOnline__c = false;
                   inactivefinal.add(Noactive);
               }

           }
        }
    }
        // Updating the status of Non active and Non logged in user status
        if(inactivefinal.size()>0)
        {
        update inactivefinal; 
        system.debug('inactivefinal updated list' + inactivefinal); 
        }

       // Below code performs load balancing among logged in users based on open cases

       Map<ID,ID> equallist = new map<ID,ID>();
       map<ID,id> Unequallist = new map<ID,id>();
       Map<id,decimal> largerlist = new Map<id,decimal>(); // used to find the larger value per group
       Map<id,decimal> recordsize = new Map<id,decimal>(); // this is used to get the original record size of each group
       for (aggregateResult lv :[select Group_Name__C, max(Case_Count__c) from Assignment_Groups__c where Active__c = 'True'AND User_Active__c = 'True' AND IsOnline__c = True GROUP BY Group_Name__c ORDER BY max(Case_Count__c)])
    {
        //largerlist.add(lv.maxval);
        largerlist.put((ID)lv.get('Group_Name__C'), (decimal)lv.get('expr0'));
     }
 system.debug('casecount of users for each group with max value' + largerlist);
    for(Assignment_Group_Name__c q : [select id,(select id,Group_Name__c,User__c,Case_Count__c,IsOnline__c,Active__c,User_Active__c from Assignment_Groups__r where Active__c = 'True'AND User_Active__c = 'True' AND IsOnline__c = True) from Assignment_Group_Name__c])
    {
                recordsize.put(q.id,q.Assignment_Groups__r.size());
                system.debug('size' + q.Assignment_Groups__r.size());
        for(Assignment_Groups__c eq: q.Assignment_Groups__r)
        {
             if(q.id ==eq.Group_Name__c && eq.IsOnline__c == True)
             {  
                if(largerlist.get(eq.Group_Name__c) == eq.Case_Count__c)
                 {
                  equallist.put(eq.Id,eq.User__c);
                  system.debug('max value equal records for each group' + eq);
                 }
                else
                 {
                  Unequallist.put(eq.id,eq.User__c);   
                  system.debug('lower values records for each group' + eq);
                }
             }
        }
      }
        system.debug('original reocrd sizes for each grp' + recordsize);

    Map<id,decimal> equalsize = new Map<id,decimal>(); // It's used to store the count of largest values or same records from each group
for(Assignment_Group_Name__c ar : [select id from Assignment_Group_Name__c])
{
    for(aggregateResult i :[select count(id) from Assignment_Groups__c where case_count__c =: largerlist.get(ar.id) AND Group_Name__c =: ar.id])
       {
           system.debug('count of larger or same value users per group' + i);
        equalsize.put(ar.id,(decimal)i.get('expr0'));
       }
}   
system.debug('equal size' + equalsize);

 for(Assignment_Groups__c ar : [select id,Group_Name__c,User__c,Case_Count__c from Assignment_Groups__c where Active__c = 'True'AND User_Active__c = 'True' AND ID IN :equallist.keyset()])
{
  if(recordsize.get(ar.Group_Name__c) == equalsize.get(ar.Group_Name__c))
  {
      Unequallist.put(ar.id,ar.user__C);
  }

}
system.debug('final unequal list'  + Unequallist);


        if(Unequallist.size() > 0)
        {
           return Unequallist;
        }
        else 
        {
           return equallist;
        }
       //return null;
}
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
private class TestMethodCls3 {

    static testMethod void myTest1() {

        // This code runs as the system user

        User u1;

        try{
          u1 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'  LIMIT 1];
          } catch (QueryException qe){

        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

        for(User u : users){
            if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true){
              u1 = u;
              break;
        }
        }

        }

        System.debug(u1);

       //*****Create Queue 
        system.runAs(u1){
       Group testGroup = new Group ();
       testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
       testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
       insert testGroup;

       QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
       testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
       testQueue.SObjectType = 'Case';
       insert testQueue;

       // Second Queue       
       Group testGroup2 = new Group ();
       testGroup2.Name = 'TestQueue2';
       testGroup2.Type = 'Queue';
       insert testGroup2;

       QueueSObject testQueue2 = new QueueSObject();
       testQueue2.QueueId = testGroup2.id;
       testQueue2.SObjectType = 'Case';
       insert testQueue2;


       test.starttest();

        //Run test

        //Assign Case with out any Assignment Groups
        Case c1 = new Case (subject='testcase',tempOwnerID__c=testGroup2.id, OwnerID=u1.id); //tempOwnerID__c=testGroup2.id,  
        insert c1;
        update c1;


        //Create Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Case');
        insert ag1;


        //Add bad queue name
        Assignment_Group_Queues__c agqBad = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name='Bad Queue',Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );

        try {
            insert agqBad; 
        } catch (DmlException e){
             System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'), e.getMessage()); 

        } //catch

        test.stoptest();
        }   
    }

    static testMethod void myTest2() {

        system.debug('method 2 exe');
        // This code runs as the system user       

        User u1;
 try{
          u1 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Assignment_Group_Active__c =True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'  LIMIT 1];
        } catch (QueryException qe){

        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

        for(User u : users){
            if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true){
              u1 = u;
              break;
        }
        }

        }

        System.debug(u1);

       //*****Create Queue 
        system.runAs(u1)
        {
       Group testGroup = new Group ();
       testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
       testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
       insert testGroup;

       QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
       testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
       testQueue.SObjectType = 'Case';
       insert testQueue;

       // Second Queue       
       Group testGroup2 = new Group ();
       testGroup2.Name = 'TestQueue2';
       testGroup2.Type = 'Queue';
       insert testGroup2;

       QueueSObject testQueue2 = new QueueSObject();
       testQueue2.QueueId = testGroup2.id;
       testQueue2.SObjectType = 'Case';
       insert testQueue2;


       test.starttest();

        //Run test


        //Create Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Case');
        insert ag1;        

        //Add Good Queue to Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq1 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name ,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id ,Active__c = 'True');
        insert agq1;


        //Add User to Assignment Groups Users
        system.debug('user as member'+ u1.id );
        Assignment_Groups__c agu1 = new Assignment_Groups__c (User__c = u1.id, Active__c = 'true',Case_Count__c = 0,Group_Name__c = ag1.id, Last_Assignment__c = datetime.valueOf('2009-01-01 21:13:24'));
        insert agu1;
        account acc = new account (Name= 'Testacc1');
        insert acc;
        contact con = new contact(AccountID = acc.id,LastName = 'Testcon',FirstName = 'First',Email ='jdoe_test_test@doe.com');
        insert con;
        Case c2 = new Case (subject='testcase',status = 'New', OwnerID=testGroup.id,ContactID = con.id,Priority = 'Sev1',Description = 'test desc',Contact_Method__c = 'Email',Preferred_Language__c = 'English'); //Set owner ID to Queue
        insert c2;
        Id recid= Schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Customer Support').getRecordTypeId(); 
        Case c3 = new Case (subject='testcase 3',status = 'Unclaimed', OwnerID=u1.id,ContactID = con.id,RecordTypeId =recid); 
        insert c3;
        c3.OwnerID = testGroup.id;
        update c3;  
        list<case>caglist = new list<case>();
            for(integer i=0;i<=200;i++)
            {
                case c1 = new case(subject='testcase'+i ,status = 'Unclaimed', OwnerID=u1.id,ContactID = con.id,RecordTypeId = recid);
                caglist.add(c1);
            }
         insert caglist;
        test.stoptest();
        } 
    }

    static testMethod void myTest3() {

        // This code runs as the system user  to validate default user 
    system.debug('test method 3 exce');
        User u2;
        try{
            string DefaultUser = Label.Default_User_For_Round_Robin_Assignment;
            u2 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Profile.Name ='System Administrator' AND Name =:DefaultUser];

        } catch (QueryException qe){

        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

        for(User u : users){
            if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true)
            {
              u2 = u;
              break;
             }
        }

        }

        System.debug(u2);

       //*****Create Queue 
        system.runAs(u2)
        {
       Group testGroup = new Group ();
       testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
       testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
       insert testGroup;

       QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
       testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
       testQueue.SObjectType = 'Case';
       insert testQueue;

       test.starttest();

        //Run test        

        //Create Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Case');
        insert ag1;        

        //Add Good Queue to Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq1 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name ,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
        insert agq1;


        //Add User to Assignment Groups Users
        datetime s = system.now();
        datetime  LAT = s.addDays(-1);
        Assignment_Groups__c agu2 = new Assignment_Groups__c (User__c = u2.id,case_count__C = 3 , Active__c = 'false',Group_Name__c = ag1.id, Last_Assignment__c = s );
        insert agu2;   
        system.debug('ag 1' + agu2);
        Case c3 = new Case (subject='testcase', status = 'New',OwnerID=testGroup.id); //Set owner ID to Queue
        insert c3;
       // update c3;
        test.stoptest();
        }  
    }

    static testMethod void myTest4() 
    {

        // This code runs as the system user for validating unique Queue 

        User u1;

        try{
          u1 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'  LIMIT 1];
        } catch (QueryException qe){

        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

        for(User u : users){
            if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true){
              u1 = u;
              break;
        }
        }

        }

        System.debug(u1);

       //*****Create Queue 
        system.runAs(u1)
        {
       Group testGroup = new Group ();
       testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
       testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
       insert testGroup;

       QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
       testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
       testQueue.SObjectType = 'Case';
       insert testQueue;


       test.starttest();

        //Run test

        //Create Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Case');
        insert ag1;        

        //Add Good Queue to Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq1 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name ,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
        insert agq1;

          //Test for AG-Queues already assigned to another Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq2 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
        try {
            insert agq2;
        } catch (DmlException e){
             System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'), e.getMessage()); 
        } //catch

        test.stoptest();
        } 
    }

    static testMethod void myTest5() 
    {

       system.debug('test method 5 executing ');
        // This code runs as the system user for testing the last assignment date
        user U5;
        user U6;
        try{

          U5 = [select Id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Assignment_Group_Active__c =True AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
          U6 = [select id from User WHERE IsActive=True AND Assignment_Group_Active__c =True AND Profile.Name = 'Customer Support' LIMIT 1];
         system.debug('user 5' +U5 );
         system.debug('user 6' +U6);
        } 
        catch (QueryException qe){

        List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData FROM User WHERE IsActive = true LIMIT 1000];

        for(User u : users){
            if(u.Profile.PermissionsModifyAllData = true)
            {
              u5 = u;
              break;
             }
        }

        }

        System.debug(u5);

       //*****Create Queue 
        system.runAs(u5)
        {
       Group testGroup = new Group ();
       testGroup.Name = 'TestQueue';
       testGroup.Type = 'Queue';
       insert testGroup;

       QueueSObject testQueue = new QueueSObject();
       testQueue.QueueId = testGroup.id;
       testQueue.SObjectType = 'Case';
       insert testQueue;

       test.starttest();

        //Run test        

        //Create Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Name__c ag1 = new Assignment_Group_Name__c (Name='TestAG', Type__c = 'Case');
        insert ag1;        

        //Add Good Queue to Assignment Group
        Assignment_Group_Queues__c agq1 = new Assignment_Group_Queues__c(name=testGroup.Name ,Assignment_Group_Name__c = ag1.id );
        insert agq1;


        //Add User to Assignment Groups Users
       datetime s = system.now();
       datetime LAT = s.addDays(-1);
        Assignment_Groups__c agu1 = new Assignment_Groups__c (User__c = u5.id, Group_Name__c = ag1.id, Last_Assignment__c = LAT,Active__c = 'true');
        insert agu1;      
        Assignment_Groups__c agu2  = new Assignment_Groups__c (User__c = u6.id,Group_Name__c = ag1.id, Last_Assignment__c = system.now(),Active__c = 'true');
        insert agu2;
            list<case> bulkcase = new list<case>();
            for(integer i=0;i<=200;i++)
            {
                Case c3 = new Case (subject='testcase'+i, OwnerID=testGroup.id);  //Set owner ID to Queue
                bulkcase.add(c3);
            }
          insert bulkcase;
        //update c3;
        test.stoptest();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify which line is not covered. Line number will not help to identify the lines here.

Comment: Could someone please have a look into this. I am trying to validate the query and found that I had an Issue with this "OwnerID IN : Activesessionusers" in aggregate query and I am unable to get some of the lines covered in Test by using the ownerID IN aggregate query.

Comment: Actually I have a before insert, before update trigger that invokes this apex class to provide me the user ids in trigger.

Comment: Check whether you are getting value in `Activesessionusers` and avoid soql and dml inside for loop.

Comment: @Reshma I am able to get the Activesessionusers details in debug log. But even though If I hardcode the user id for OwnerID in Aggregate query these lines aren't covered.

Comment: Able to get the lines covered by removing the space between colon and Activesessionusers(: Activesessionusers)